# Ruby Selenium/Watir ".select" does not do anything in Safari (any version)

Tags: ruby, selenium, safari, watir

I'm having a painful time trying to select a value in a select field in Safari. It works fine in Chrome, Firefox and IE.

It finds the object fine, but it doesn't select any value. It also doesn't return any error.

I've also tried this on multiple websites with select fields (same issue):

launch browser

```
browser = Watir::Browser.new :safari, url: "http://localhost:4444/wd/hub"
```

Set object (works fine)

```
 elTitle = @browser.element(xpath:'//select[@name="ddTitle"]')
```

Now things i've tried to select the value:

```
elTitle.option(:text => "Mrs").select
```

above returns nil, and nothing actually selected
also tried:

```
elTitle.options[1].click
```

above returns nil, and nothing actually selected
also tried:

```
elTitle.send_keys "Mrs", :tab
```

(which often results in the listbox options displayed (with the correct value with a tick next to it), but it's on top of the browser and prevents any further code from continuing - but this is another issue altogether)

```
Ruby: 2.2.6
safari v11.0.3 (High Sierra)
watir gem: 6.10.3
selenium-webdriver: 3.9.0
selenium-standalone-server: 3.9.1
```

Originally had older versions of these gems, which had the same issue, so updated them, and still have the issue. Had also tried with earlier version of Safari (v10/Sierra), which had the same issue.

I've also been unable to launch Safari Technology Preview (but this is an issue i'll raise separately)

So, in summary, has anyone been able to do ".select" on a select field in Safari?

Answer (score 0):

YOu are doing it wrong, you are calling option method for wrong object.

Try this syntax for select_list always

```
b.select_list(name: "ddTitle").select "Mrs"
```

Other syntax is

```
b.select_list(name: "ddTitle").option(text: "Mrs").select
```

`option` method has to be called for `Watir::Select` object not for `Watir::HTMLElement`, you are actually calling for `Watir::HTMLElement`, so it's not working.

Comment: Hi @Rajagopalan, thanks for the response, but your suggestions produce the same results - ie it finds the object fine, but doesn't select any value. This works fine on Chrome, Firefox and IE, so it's just Safari that's the problem.I've also tried: b.select_list(name: "ddTitle").options[0].click

Comment: @J.Irving Okay, then there may be a problem with safari driver

Comment: I've been able to launch Safari Technology Preview, and .select works fine - which means this issue is isolated to the standard Safaridriver (eg that comes with standard Safari, which I think is located here:
/System/Library/CoreServices/SafariSupport.bundle/Contents)

Comment: @J.Irving Yeah that's what I meant.